# Python deleting 0 at end of string

Tags: python, numpy

I am tring to transfer a numpy array of two strings to another numpy array.  But when every on of the strings has a value of 10 it transfers a 1.

Code:

```
import numpy as np

x= np.full(2, '', dtype=str)

y = np.array([['10', 'C']])

print(y[0, 0])
x[0] = y[0, 0]
print(x[0])
```

Output:

```
10
1
```

Comment: It's not deleting the zero, it's just using the first character.

Comment: `dtype=str` sets the dtype to a 1-character string, so all strings are truncated.

Comment: the main question is why you save numbers as string!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Numpy strings have fixed length, so you need to specify the length in the dtype. `dtype=str` defaults to length = 1. As a result, any strings are truncated to the first character.

```
x= np.full(2, '', dtype='<U10')
```

Specifies the datatype as 10-character Unicode strings.